# Choosing contrast coding in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization, contrasts

I am working on a data set with categorical variables. To apply ANN, I want to apply contrast coding to those variables. But how do I choose between coding functions in R (sum, helmert, treatment etc.) or does it matter if I choose randomly?

And also there are some continuous numerical variables too. So I want to apply normalization to my data set. How can I apply normalization to the categorical variables which are applied contrast coding.